# $_SESSION not working/ sending out wrong result in php

Tags: php, session

I am trying to navigate to a different page whenever a user clicks on a particular link [basically these are user links which navigate to user profile page when clicked].

My problem if I store the SESSION variable and display it in the same page as the link, it echos out all the emails ids corresponding to that user, but as soon as I navigate to a different page,I can see SESSION displays the wrong result [some other email id].

Here is my code.

```
<a href="?navigate=true" id="user" name="<?php echo $email; ?>" class="user"><?php echo $firstName.' '.$lastName;?></a>
```

This link is displayed as many times as there are records in the database.

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['navigate']) && $_GET['navigate'] == "true"){
  $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
  echo $_SESSION['email'];
  header('location: home.php');
}

?>
```

Now if I just echo the email like above on this page itself, it displays all the emails corresponding to that user. Like this.

```
user1 : emailid1
user2 : emailid2
```

But as soon as I navigate to home.php, the SESSION variable always prints out the first email only.

**home.php**

```
session_start();
echo 'email id is '.$_SESSION['email'];
```

I know I am going wrong somewhere but any suggestions would be of great help.

Comment: you can start session on view page and other page.

Comment: In every page where you want to use the session variable you need to start the session so every session container page first line should be session_start();

Comment: i already use that in my home.php. See my post above

Comment: I have had problems with "header(Location: ___);" in the past.  You can try adding the line "exit;" immediately following the header line, as the page continues to get processed even after the header is called.  Let me know if this helps.

Comment: nope, still the same, the first email is getting printed out everytime.

Comment: @skidadon : any suggestions yet?

Answer (score -1):

Try with below code.

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['navigate']) && $_GET['navigate'] == "true"){
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
  echo $_SESSION['email'];
  header('location: home.php');
}

?>
```

Comment: Where does `$email` come from Mitul?

Comment: @RobbieAverill  He added code, If you check the $email already there. I don't know about that

Comment: email is being fetched from some other place. If you see the same has been used in the anchor tag as name. This displays the correct result though